# Using VBA monitor the effect of changing initial data in an equation

Tags: vba, excel

I have absolutely no idea how to go about this problem, and my VBA skills are quite weak. I have this data, consisting of 3 columns and a number of rows that is not constant (it could be any number of rows).

I am looking to take each value in each column, and insert it into another sheet as a variable. These 3 columns, are different variables, so go into different cells. The effect of these changes, will then be collected and deposited in cells along each row that gave the results. that is, row 1 might be 2/3/4. along the same row, just a few cells to the right, the effects of the variables (2/3/4) on different values in the equations, are deposited.

After this runs, it moves to the next line, and performs the same operation. That is taking the values along that row, inserting it into the spread sheet and depositing the results along the same line.

The macro, then stops running at the end of the table.

Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

```
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A9").Select
    Worksheets("Rating").Range("B3") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B9").Select
    Worksheets("Rating").Range("B5") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C9").Select
    Worksheets("Rating").Range("B6") = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value


Do
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then Exit Do
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop
```

To be honest, I have no idea how to code this. Any help would be awesome.. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're looking for or why VBA is the answer (sounds like formulas would work here). If VBA is the answer, do some research (Google is awesome), try recording a macro to help get you started, and edit your question (add the code you're working with) when you've hit a brick wall. `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist`

Comment: I wrote the code I just added. It only takes the values from the first cell locations, and inserts it into the cells, but does not move to the next line. The Do loop, is supposed to monitor the values until the cells become empty, then it stops. I know a For Next statement should be inserted in the statements, but its construction is proving a bit difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't moving to the next line because your `Do Loop` is in the wrong spot. For example:

```
Do 
    'This is where you put the code you want to do for each line.
Loop
```

If you use a `Do Loop`, you won't need to use `For Next` (you only need to have one loop to do what you need).

Honestly, this is how I would code what you have above:

**Untested**

```
Option Explicit  
Sub Test()

Dim sht1 As Worksheet  
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim ii As Long

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Rating")
i = 9
ii = 3
Do
    sht2.Cells(ii,"B") = sht1.Cells(i,"A").Value    
    sht2.Cells(ii + 2,"B") = sht1.Cells(i,"B").Value      
    sht2.Cells(ii + 3,"B") = sht1.Cells(i,"C").Value    
    i = i + 1
    ii = ii + 4
Loop Until sht1.Cells(i,"A") = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: ARich you are a genius without doubt... Tried it.. and it gave exactly what i wanted, i even modified it, to output results from other cells. Then I changed the ii = 4, to ii = 0, because it was inputting values into locked cells, which i was trying to avoid. Thanks a lot really.. You have been of massive help...